# AngularJS ng-repeat display content in separate view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on a basic news feed app. What I need is for a specific news article, *entry.content*,  to display in a separate view after a click. Both controllers have access to the data, but I need a synchronized click event so the second controller knows which specific article to display. I've been working on this for awhile & couldn't find relevant links on google or here where a secondary view was involved. I need a separate view b/c I have to add a lot more HTML to that page & eventually click(previous/next) between articles. I have an example which is working where the click event happens, but the content displays in the current view then hides after click.

I have a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lk66pRb7A6DkGM7NQKF7?p=preview

Here is the index.html code:

```
<body ng-app="FeedApp">
  <h1>News Feed</h1>
  <div ng-controller="NewsCtrl">

    <div id="main">
    <div ng-view=""><!-- angular yield --></div>
    </div> <!-- main -->

  </div> <!-- NewsCtrl -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body> <!-- FeedApp -->
```

Here is the home.html code:

```
<div ng-repeat="new in news">
  <h3 ng-repeat="entry in new.entries" ng-if="$index < 3">
    {{entry.title}}
    </br>
        <a href="#/" ng-click="show = !show">Display this story</a></br>
        <a href="#/article" target="_self" ng-click="show = !show">Desired: click this Link, go to #/article & display this story</a>
        <p class="news-entries" ng-show="show" ng-bind-html="TrustSnippet(entry.content)"></p>
 </h3>
</div> <!-- new in news -->
```

Currently, in the article.html file I only have a back button as I'm not sure what to put in there. All other code is in the Plunker, but I can add here if it will help.

I was thinking this might be be solved using current $index value, but I just don't know at this point.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just want to use $routeParams like so:

here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3oV9ZjjpyQmWBzRoqcoH?p=preview)

**route**

```
.when("/article/:articleId", { . .
```

**Link**

```
<a href="#/article/{{$index}}"  . . .
```

**Param**

```
FeedApp.controller("ArticlesCtrl", ["$scope", "$routeParams", '$http',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    var index = $routeParams.articleId;
```

**Article Object**

```
$scope.article = $scope.news[0].entries[index];
```

I would omit the `entries` bit altogether and I would probably use a factory to manage/maintain the data.